# XamlReader error in WP8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I copy this code from MSDN [Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx)

```
string xaml = "<Ellipse Name=\"EllipseAdded\" Width=\"300.5\" Height=\"200\" Fill=\"Red\"       \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>";
object ellipse = XamlReader.Load(xaml);
```

But I throw an error

```
The text associated with this error code could not be found. illegal 
qualified name character [Line: 1 Position: 68]
```

Please help me fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XAML, it seems the xmlns is missing.

```
string xaml = "<Ellipse Name=\"EllipseAdded\" Width=\"300.5\" Height=\"200\" Fill=\"Red\"       xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>";
```